# Display raw binary data of an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing

I'm trying to convert the raw binary data of an image and then display it.

Steps to approach to the problem,

**1.** I have saved the raw binary data of images in my database.

Preview:

[image]

**2.** Fetch & Convert the data into a blob and then into a blob url.

```
const image = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([ project.image ], { type: 'image/jpg' }))
```

where `project.image` contains the raw binary data.

**3.** Add the url to the `img` tag.

[image]

**4.** Problem: Not displaying the image as expected.

Preview:

[image]

I have spent many hours not knowing what is wrong here. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I see here [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) they want the mime type to be `image/jpeg`. Not `image/jpg`.

Comment: @RobMoll Thanks for your comment. I've tried it but it still doesn't work.